# Gnome 3.8.4 can I upgrade to Gnome 3.10?

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3

I'm using Centos 7.

```
gnome-shell --version
Gnome Shell 3.8.4
```

1. does this mean I'm using Gnome 3.8.4?
2. can I upgrade to Gnome 3.10?
3. Are there any how-tos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: does this mean I'm using Gnome 3.8.4?

Yes you're using GNOME 3.8.4 from that `gnome-shell` output.

> Q2: can I upgrade to Gnome 3.10?

Yes but I've found no repositories that offer it as of yet so your only recourse is to compile it yourself from sources. You can make this a little less painful by trying to use the source RPMS (SRPMS) from a Fedora release that offers it, that's close to CentOS 7. F19 + F20 would be good candidates.

I'll warn you though that this can be trick to do yourself, so I'd probably not attempt it myself.

> Q3: Are there any how-tos?

None that I was able to find. It's typically the case that you're picking CentOS because you want ultra stability. The cost of this stability is that you lag behind in versions.

If you truly want to use GNOME 3.10 then you're much better off moving to one of the Fedora releases, specifically F20 or F21.

Answer (score 0):

What the previous person said, and if you're up for the challenge, you could download the source packages from the GNOME git repo, and compile everything yourself. But that would require you to uninstall GNOME, all related dependencies, then you will have to correct any build errors, if any, apply some patches, wait a couple hours, to days for it to compile, and repeat if any new version of GNOME that interests you comes out.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME has a mechanism for building dev versions with [JHBuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeLove/JhbuildIntroduction).  It won't replace the packaged version of GNOME included in CentOS7 (which is probably for the best).